# Qual a versão do conector MySql no Azure?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-azure

estou iniciando com a plataforma Azure e fui testar um uma web api em Asp.Net com EF6 e MySql, no entanto quando subo a aplicação para o server do Azure e tento chamar um serviço que consulta meu banco é retornada uma página de erro do conector MySql. Alguem sabe me dizer qual a versão que a Microsoft disponibiliza e se dá para instalar um versão mais nova na minha conta do Azure?

Na minha aplicação utilizo EF6 e o connector MySql é o 6.9.

Desde já muito obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O provedor de nuvem Azure não possui configurações de conectores pré definidos.

Todo conector que você precisar usar, você deve subir junto com seu projeto web.

Ou seja, se você precisa de um MySQL Connector, basta embarca-lo no seu projeto web via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mysql.data). Como está usando EntityFramework, segue os conectores necessários:

- [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) - `Install-Package MySql.Data`
- [MySql.Data.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/) - `Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity`

Assim, você não depende de nenhuma pré definição do ambiente. Você embarca o conector que precisa, na versão que necessita e tudo funciona como planejado.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo algumas tentativa encontrei a resposta, a versão do connector .Net MySql no Azure é o 6.7.9, por isso estou utilizando agora em minha aplicação o EntityFramework 5.

Se alguém souber onde fica as documentações do azure onde eu poderia ter encontrado essa informação mais fácil eu agradeceria.